# Laravel login setup

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have created a registration form with some of my simple php code in the laravel framework. Now I honestly have no idea how to make a user log into my page.

In the documentation I see something like this below. I guess this is it, but I have no idea what should be inside of these variables? Well, yes the user is registered, his login in the database is "login1" and password "password123" but how do I check it?

I am reading some tutorials but they contain a lot of unexplained code that I don't understand and I think there is no point just to copy someone's work that I will be not able to fix someday when I mess up something.

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password)))
{
    return Redirect::intended('dashboard');
}
```

EDIT:
This is what my registration looks like:

```
public function register(){

        $nick = $_POST['nickReg'];
        $name = $_POST['first_nameReg'];
        $surname = $_POST['last_nameReg'];
        $email = $_POST['emailReg'];
        $password = Hash::make($_POST['passwordReg']);

        DB::insert('INSERT INTO `users` (nick, first_name, last_name, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', array($nick, $name, $surname, $email, $password));
        return Redirect::to('/intro');
}
```

Comment: The documentation of Laravel describes it in detail. Your login script is right,  there can be many failures you did. Please give us more related information like for example did you hashed the password in the database?

Comment: Any particular reason why you use laravel 4 instead of laravel 5.1 that has build in authentication?

Comment: @nipeco Thank you for being interested in my problem. I have edited my topic adding my registration function

Comment: @TimvanUum Yes, I am beginner junior php developer and we use laravel 4 at work. So i wanted to use the same framework

Comment: @divHelper11 ok understandable. I see a lot of things that can be improved. Like the use of models and the request object. Before jumping directly into code I really advise you to watch this series: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch it taught me so much! I think it will do the same for you.

Comment: @TimvanUum I am already excited. Thank you a lot for this link!

Comment: @divHelper11 You're welcome. Laravel is very well documented. Try to keep that in mind while programming. I started too with just coding, thinking I know it. Try to look up everything you do to see if it can be improved. Do that and you'll become a master in Laravel very soon. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after like 20 hours spent on learning I have figured it out myself.
The variables $email and $password in Auth::attempt are just values received from login form. The laravel itself takes care of them, and makes me get logged in.